# How to check if an object contains a value?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if an object contains any value. The following function works fine if the object is a String type but I was looking to replace this with a generic way without checking for the type. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
 public void SetValue(int id, object fieldData)
    {
        if (fieldData!=null)
        {
            if (fieldData.GetType() == typeof(String) && fieldData.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        SetLOValue(id, fieldData);
    }
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "object contains a value".

Comment: [C# Ternary Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx) could be of use to you.

Comment: Do you consider 0, `DateTime.MinValue`, and `DBNull.Value` to be "values"?

Comment: if(fieldData!=null) will return true if the object hold some value

Comment: the answer depends on what types you could be checking and what you consider to be a valid value.  Technically, value types always have a value and reference types are either null or have a value.  If there are specific conditions you want to consider not a value (like `String.Empty` in your example), you need to specify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for default types if you make it generic, but you have to be sure that's what you want. i.e. is 0 a valid number in your usage?

```
if (fieldData == default(T))
{
  return;
}
```

Alternatively, you could switch to [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) types.

```
if (fieldData.HasValue)...
```

Comment: what is type T referring to, in your example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dynamic`.

The CLR determines the type at runtime and gets the property.